# Google Glass Mirror Api Playground not inserting correctly

Tags: google-mirror-api

I have run the Glassware starter project and been able to add cards to my timeline and see them on my glass hardware. That site url is:

https://glass-java-starter-demo.appspot.com/

But when I go to the Mirror API Playground and follow the directions, authorizing and push the blue insert button, nothing gets inserted on Glass. I have waited as long as 12 hours and still nothing.

Further, something is being inserted as you can see in this API Console screen capture:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions, I have recreated my client id many times being very careful to include the javascript origin, I have tried making my client id set up look like the one in the cat demo project instructions. But no luck.

The playground gives no error and based on the console feedback I believe it is going somewhere just not to my glass hardware. Its supposed to insert into my glass hardware right? This is how we are supposed to test rendering of timeline items, correct?

Comment: Can you confirm that the items do appear in the "Timeline" tab in the Playground? Also, can you make sure that you are logged-in using the correct user account (the same account that is used on your Glass device)?

Comment: I can confirm both.  The timeline tab becomes active (hiding the template tab) and my card is shown near the bottom half of the playground screen.  Also, I am logged in as the same account as the Glass device, I can see this in the upper right corner of the screen, where my email and avatar are shown.

Comment: Regarding the logged-in user, unfortunately having your avatar and email show up on the upper right corner might not be a good indication. The best way to try is to start over from an incognito window: when you click on authorize, if the pop-up stays open, make sure that the user that grants access is the correct user.

Comment: It works, and actually I apologize my test from earlier today worked as well, its just Glass didn't have a network connection.  I don't know what the solution was based on this, but I am now able to post timeline cards from the playground.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but this can no longer be reproduced.  One suggestion from Alain was to always start fresh in a new incognito window and to be sure you are logged in as the same user the glass hardware is registered with.  My working Client Id has two "Redirect URIs" and one "JavaScript origins".